Will the energy that makes me up exist forever?
Since energy wont cease to exist like the law conservation of energy states. Does this mean after I die my energy will still exist forever? I Don't mean religion or anything on that scale I just mean energy that makes up me now?

This question is similar to: Life and Death, and Energy Conservation. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's questionable if it is ever "your" energy. In physics energy is just energy, it doesn't belong to any particular individual (or if it does, it makes no difference to the laws of physics).
